# How to tell what value types are initialized to by the CLR

Tags: c#

This pertains to C# & the .NET Framework specifically.

It's best practice not to initialize the following types in the .NET framework because the CLR initializes them for you:

int, 
bool, etc.

and same for setting an object to null (I believe).

For example you do not need to do this and in fact it's a performance hit (drops in the bucket or not):

```
int Myvar = 0;
```

Just need `int Myvar;` and that's it.  the CLR will initialize it to int.

I obviously just "know" from programming that int is set to 0 by default and bool to false.

And also setting an object to null because the CLR does it for you.
But how can you tell what those primitive types are set to.  I tried opening up Reflector to take a look at int32 and bool but could not figure out how they are initialized by default.

I looked on msdn and I don't see it there either.  Maybe I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a table, MSDN is your friend: [Default Values Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You want a list like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc(VS.80).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily make a program that prints default(T) for all T of interest.

Comment: Yeah, and you'd get 0 for all value types.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is basically zeroed out, so just take it from there. Int/Double/etc 0. String, or other structure, probably String.Empty, Guid.Empty, etc. bool, false (0 in other languages.)

It is pretty intuitive.

Comment: References, including String references, are initialized to null. String.Empty != null.

Comment: String is not a structure, it's a class.  The default value will be null, like any other reference type.  Otherwise this is correct: all value types are zeroed out, any members that are reference types will be null.

Answer (score 0):

For C#, here is the list of all the value types - click the link for each to find out what its default is:

[Value Types Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx)

Comment: Ok, but where does it state the default values the CLR sets them to if at all?

Comment: I'm not after "what" is an int, uint, I already know "what".  I'm after where does it officially state the default values that the CLR will assign if you do not explicitly assign...which is a best practice for performance implications.

Comment: Or if MSDN states how can I arrive to find out (using reflector to look at how it's initialized if you don't explicitely initialze it to zero or what have you), etc.  I'm talking about the default initializations when not explicitely stated by the compiler here is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a long shot, but I'd say that

```
default( T )
```

will give you pretty accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the app and check to see what the initial value is prior to when you change it.  There might be a better answer out there, but for the sake of closing this thread, I'm just posting a quick and dirty solution.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int iTest;
            string sTest;
            double dTest;
            bool bTest;
            float fTest;

            // stop debugger here
            Console.WriteLine();

            iTest = 0;
            sTest = "";
            dTest = 0.0;
            bTest = false;
            fTest = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DontInitializeVariables.aspx

here we go.  Simply: Value types are initialized to 0 and reference types are initialized to null